# Using Qualify with Rank in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, rank, dense-rank

I am trying to get latest two month start dates for a particular product when it was sold in Teradata.Since a product was sold in multiple months , I should only get the latest two selling months for each product.

Trying to use Qualify with Dense Rank :

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT, MONTH_START_DATE,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY MONTH_START_DATE DESC ) AS RNK
FROM  EMP_TABLE 
HERE PRODUCT = 'SOAP'
```

This will give me Different months with Rank and Product. Something like this :

```
+---------+------------------+------+
| Product | Month_start_date | RNK  |
+---------+------------------+------+
| SOAP    | 2016-12-01       | 1    |
| SOAP    | 2016-11-01       | 2    | 
| SOAP    | 2016-10-01       | 3    |
+---------+------------------+------+
```

But if I rewrite code to get only top 2 :

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT, MONTH_START_DATE
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY MONTH_START_DATE DESC ) AS RNK
FROM  EMP_TABLE
WHERE PRODUCT = 'SOAP' 
QUALIFY  RNK < 3
```

I always get only the top rank result. What is the reason for this ? The solution is writing a subquery but wanted to understand the reason behind 'Qaulify' giving only top row.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this your actual query? Your Select returns only a single row? Works as expected for me, what's your Teradata release? Btw, depending on your actual data it might be more efficient to replace the `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY 1,2` and `RANK` instead of `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: @dnoeth : Thanks for the suggestion. I have rephrased the query using `Group by` and using `rank`. However , my question was more related to Qualify. Why it isn't giving top two and only giving only one result ?

Comment: It might be because of the `Dense_rank` and not using `group by` combination.

Comment: It's working as expected when I try a similar query. That's why I asked about your TD release and more details.

Comment: @dnoeth: Its Teradata 14.0

Comment: And just for reference - I am still referring to the query written in the question. Changing `distinct` to `group by` and `dense_rank` to `rank` helped.However , I am trying to know the reason why it's not the same when we use `dense_rank` with `distinct`

Comment: It can't be 14.0 because DENSE_RANK was implemented in 14.10. What's returned by `SELECT InfoData FROM dbc.dbcinfoV WHERE InfoKey = 'RELEASE'`

Comment: I was checking the provider version not the database version. It is indeed 14.10. The value returned is `14.10.07.05`